# OpenWRT looking for files in staging_dir at compile time

Tags: autotools, automake, openwrt

I'm trying to compile some OpenWRT packages, A and B, where B depends on some header files from A.

These packages use automake, and when I compile A, it copies its header files to `build_dir/../package/include/...`

The problem is that now I need to use them in package B, and when I add the command `someheaders_HEADERS`, OpenWRT looks for them in `staging_dir/.../usr/include`.

I could copy these files over on the `\install` phase of the OpenWRT compile process, but that seems a bad approach.

How can this be correctly solved?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest below 2 things,

If your package A provide pkg config (.pc) file then you can add below code in Package B makefile.am

```
yourapp_CFLAGS = $(pkg-config --cflags <Package-A's .PC file name>)
```

or simply add below code in makefile.am for package B

```
yourapp_CFLAGS = -I($CURDIR)/../PackageA/include/
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The problem is exactly where should I be getting the PackageA files. Gettings them from the source directory doesn't seem to be correct. Should I be able to get them from `some_root_dir/usr/lib` or `some_root_dir/usr/include`

Comment: In that case you can put PakageA's header as nobase_include_HEADERS = "" it will copy them in sys_root/usr/include/ and use it in PackageB compilation